# Releasing after removal from an array & reference pointers

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, autorelease

So some where i have a leak which is related to deleting an object under certain circumstances.

Premise: 
- I have an NSMutableArray of Tree objects (a Tree object knows how to draw itself).
- I have a reference pointer (Tree *selected) which basically points to whatever tree i last touched.
- Note that the *selected pointer is a weak reference.

Ok, so far so good.

Problem:
The leak arises when i delete a Tree. From the list i make sure the tree being deleted is releasing everything internally before removing it from the array (removing it from the array should automatically call release on it).

What i tried:
I noticed that my Tree *selected pointer is being assigned the touched tree via the self property:

> self.selected = tree;

...and by doing this i know that it is being retained. So what i tried to do was call:

> [self.selected release];

I called this right after the tree is removed from the array.
...but at which point it crashes essentially stating it was already released.

Question:
Why am i getting this error message? I removed it from the array, however my self.selected pointer still has a retained count, thus shouldn't i be releasing it?

Perhaps I should set it to nil after the removal process?
Or, perhaps I should set it to autorelease BEFORE the removal process?

Comment: Let me revise my question:
Since the *selected pointer has a retained count of the object in the array, why would removing that object from the array cause it to be deallocated? The fact that i had a retained reference to it should've prevented it from being deallocated, correct???

Comment: So what i did was assign the *selected pointer without using the self keyword. After doing the removal process, i dont call release on the ref pointer nor do i set it to nil.

So far no leak!!

Comment: Shit. leaks, leaks, leaks, it's back.

Comment: You say that `selected` is a weak reference, but then say that it's being retained. In a non-GC context, the term "weak reference" usually means that it's not retained. Can you confirm which is the case?

Answer (score 1):

Don't attempt to micromanage the retaining/releasing of your `selected` instance variable. If you want `selected` to be a weak reference, declare it with the `assign` attribute:

```
@property(nonatomic, assign) Tree *selected;
```

That way it will not be retained when you assign a value to it. Conceptually, it will "piggyback" on the reference that your `NSMutableArray` is keeping. So when you remove something from your NSMutableArray, do it a bit like this:

```
if (self.selected == toBeRemoved)
    self.selected = nil;
[myArray removeObject:toBeRemoved];
```

If you didn't explicitly specify `assign` and your property was retaining its contents, you were most likely getting an exception because the next assignment to `self.selected` after removing an element caused another `-release` message to be sent to the old value, which had already been released by your `[self.selected release]` message.

Answer (score 0):

What's [probably] happening is `selected` points to a deallocated object, not nothing.

I'd try

```
self.selected = nil;
```

instead of releasing it explicitly. That should take care of the retain count, too.

Answer (score 0):

basically, i was assigning my weak references using 'self', thus internally calling retain. i removed the 'self' and now things are fine and dandy. :)
thanks!